# Android handling permission disabling from system settings

Tags: android, permissions, crash

From app I gave the required permission for my app. While my app is running, I went to system settings page and revoked the permission. The app is crashing. Will we be able to handle this?.

Comment: On turning off the permission from the settings page, Android system kills the corresponding process and recreates the app. Hence this cant be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 (Marshmallow, API 23) switched from an install-time permission model to a runtime permission model. Now instead of the user granting all permissions at runtime, you the developer are responsible for requesting permissions at runtime and responding appropriately.

You should begin by reading the [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) documentation. So that you can properly request permissions on devices running Marshmallow.

To prevent your app from crashing, you need to call `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` to see if you have a permission *before* attempting to call a method that requires a permission. However, this is only half the equation since you still need to request the permission if you don't already have it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whatever you are explaining is "How to handle run time permission". My question is, The user grants the permission and i am accessing the resource. Now the user can revoke this permission by going to the system settings page. In this case the app just crashed, can you suggest a way for handling this case in an elegant way?.

Comment: Your question specifically stated "Then I went to the system settings page and revoked the permission." If the user has granted the permission and you are still experiencing a crash, you need to either update your question with the correct details or post a new question. Either way, you should include the Exception that shows in your logcat.